# CSS Div not centreing

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and to improve my skills i've been trying to recreate differnt sites by myself. I'm currently trying to recreate the notion home page but i have an issue. my img div is not centring? This is probably an easy fix but if someone could help i'd apprectiate it :)
Here is my HTML:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");

:root {
  --primary-text: #111111;
  --secondary-text: #91908f;
  --background: #fffefc;
  --btn-primary: #e16259;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--b);
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

/* NAV */

.nav {
  width: 100;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin: 15px 50px;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #111111;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 35px;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li {
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #91908f;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
}

/* HERO */

.nav-img {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Notion Logo">
    <div class="nav">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>   
            <li><span>|</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>         
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>         
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero-img">
        <img src="img/hero.webp" alt="Illustration of 3 people using laptop computers on seperate desks with different expressions">
        </div>

        <h1>All-in-one workspace</h1>
        <h4>One tool for your whole team. Write, plan, and get organized.</h4>

        <form action="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email...">
            <button class='btn-primary' type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
        <p>For teams & individuals - web, mobile, Mac, Windows</p>
    </div>
```

..

Comment: You are talking about an "img div". There are two images in your code, the second one is inside a div, so probably you mean that one. In HTML, the `div` container of that image has class `.hero-img`. In CSS, you don't have any rule for a class with that name - just `.nav-img` --> is that the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different things you need to consider when learning to code, first of all, it's important to use the new html5 semantic element `header` where you can place your logo and `nav`

```
<header>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Notion Logo">
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Product</a>
        <a href="#">Download</a>
        <a href="#">Resources</a>
        <a href="#">Pricing</a> |
        <a href="#">Careers</a>
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="#">Log In</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

*note: a `nav` element doesn’t have to contain a list as mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav), and you can style them easily. The `img` centering issue came from the `header` wrong styling `.nav{float: right;}` `.nav{ width: 100}` needs to have px, %, or vw example `.nav{width: 100px;}`, `.nav{width: 60vw;}`, `.nav{width: 60%;}` then you can easily center the other elements vertically like below

```css
.center-vertically {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="header-sub">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Notion Logo" />
            <nav>
                <a href="#">Product</a>
                <a href="#">Download</a>
                <a href="#">Resources</a>
                <a href="#">Pricing</a> |
                <a href="#">Careers</a>
                <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                <a href="#">Log In</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    
<div class="center-vertically">
  <div class="centered-item">
    <img src="https://www.notion.so/cdn-cgi/image/f=auto,w=1080,q=100/front-static/pages/product/hero.png" alt="Illustration of 3 people using laptop computers on seperate desks with different expressions" />
  </div>
  <h1>All-in-one workspace</h1>
  <h4>One tool for your whole team. Write, plan, and get organized.</h4>

  <form action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email..." />
    <button class="btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
  <p>For teams & individuals - web, mobile, Mac, Windows</p>
  <div class="centered-item">anything you want to add</div>
</div>
```

You can style your header, and there is an awesome resource to follow to learn properly [Freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/)

Comment: Thank you very much <3 appreciate the help